# How to fixed statement is not covered for function using React Testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

Below is the code snippet
[image]

Can someone help here?  Already written some code

```
it("Should call on change handler - ", async () => {
    render(
      <Provider store={mockStore()}>
        <ComplaintForm {...defaultProps} />
      </Provider>
    );

    user.setup();
    const storeComplaintHandler = mockFunc;
    const storeDispositionHandler = mockFunc;
    const complaintAndDispositionSel = mockFunc;

    const complaintDropdown = screen.queryByTestId("ddlComplaint");
    await user.click(complaintDropdown);
    waitFor(() => expect(storeComplaintHandler).toHaveBeenCalled());
    waitFor(() => expect(complaintAndDispositionSel).toHaveBeenCalled());

    const dispositionDropdown = screen.queryByTestId("ddlComplaintDisposition");
    await user.click(dispositionDropdown);
    waitFor(() => expect(storeDispositionHandler).toHaveBeenCalled());
    waitFor(() => expect(complaintAndDispositionSel).toHaveBeenCalled());
  });
```

Comment: Could you add in some additional information or get specific with the question you are asking?

Comment: Can't help without seeing the code under test